# iCarousel right to left scroll moving to left to right

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, icarousel

Am using iCarousel for my ipad application ,
carousel type is iCarouselTypeLinear. while scrolling to right to left it's moving to left to right.

please help me to fix this issue.

Comment: Can you post some code, for example how you implemented it?

Comment: i downloaded from github repository [link](https://github.com/nicklockwood/iCarousel/downloads)

Comment: my ITEM_SPACING value is 860 , and also carouselShouldWrap is true

Comment: @Anand : Hi have you got any solution for this ?