# How to change iCarousel autoScrollDirection from left to right To Right to left

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcode, icarousel

I have gone through many links and checked [iCarousel right to left scroll moving to left to right](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10121429/icarousel-right-to-left-scroll-moving-to-left-to-right) too, but did not get any solution to my issue :

I am using **[iCarousel](https://github.com/nicklockwood/iCarousel)** custom library with **enabling Autoscroll** but in this library, it only allows Left to right scroll direction for autoscroll, my issue is I want it in reverse (Right to left)direction.can anyone help me with this, please.

Thank you

Comment: i have downloaded the code from your given link in question and run the Example Project. it will allow to scroll both side.

Comment: i have run iCarouselExample (iCarouselExample project) from library

Comment: yes . you are right but i am talking about Autoscroll ,from that folder run **ButtonsDemo** project and in viewDidLoad set   carousel.type = iCarouselTypeLinear;
    carousel.autoscroll = 1.0 ;

Comment: autoscroll is only allowed in one direction

Comment: okay got it your issue. it will autoscroll one side only. let me check

Comment: if you give autoscroll = -1.0 then it will autoscroll right to left but its showing last value

Comment: Thank you so much Man! it worked with  :  **carousel.autoscroll = -1.0 ;
    [carousel scrollToItemAtIndex:0 animated:YES];**

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163691/discussion-between-nirav-kotecha-and-anjali-bhimani).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

change the autoscroll value from 1 to -1

```
carousel.autoscroll = -1.0
[carousel scrollToItemAtIndex:0 animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 0):

If you will set `autoscroll` property so, it will scroll every time.

Just add only line of code you will get the direction as per your want.

If you want to scroll with RTL support. Add below line.

Sort your data model array in reverse order, so that the item you want to be first appears at the end of the array.

After loading the carousel, set its index to the last item, which you can do by calling

```
carousel.currentItemIndex = array.count - 1;
```